Возможность работы с определённым ID пользователя в строке, выведенной через foreach
Возникла проблема. Через foreach я перебираю массив с неверифицированными участниками, имеющие id, nickname и email. По нажатию на кнопки acceptUser / declineUser я должен отправлять POST-запрос на страницу /api/accept_request.php / /api/decline_request.php, отправляя в теле запроса свой id ($adminId в коде), и id пользователя, в строке которого я нажимаю на соответствующую кнопку. На данный момент я с помощью JavaScript передаю id юзера через атрибут data-userid и обрабатываю запрос через fetch. Однако проблема заключается в том, что этот самый атрибут можно спокойной изменить через код элемента и код начнёт использовать уже изменённый id. Как в моём примере перебора пользователей через foreach можно реализовать подобный функционал? Предполагаю, что каждую кнопку нужно обернуть в форму на сопутствующие action, однако как мне передавать id именно того пользователя, напротив которого я использую эти кнопки?
Мой код:
    <section class="section">
    <h1 class="section__title">Верификация пользователей</h1>
    <p class="section__subtitle">На данный момент <strong><?php echo count($unverifyUsers); ?></strong> чел. ждут верификации аккаунта.</p>
    <div class="verify-list">
        <?php foreach ($unverifyUsers as $unverifyUser) : ?>
        <div class="verify-row">
            <p>Пользователь: <strong><?php echo $unverifyUser['nickname']; ?></strong>. Почта: <strong><?php echo $unverifyUser['email']; ?></strong>.</p>
            <div class="verify-actions">
                <button id="acceptUser" data-userid="<?php echo $unverifyUser['id'] ?>" class="verify-action verify-action--primary">Подтвердить</button>
                <button id="declineUser" data-userid="<?php echo $unverifyUser['id'] ?>" class="verify-action verify-action--gray">Отклонить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</section>


Гипотетичкски, на стороне клиента можно изменить любые данные, поэтому сервер никогда не должен доверять клиенту. Тем более, что все данные лежат в HTML разметке. Так же не понятно, что вообще делает javaScript и как(кода в вопросе нет). Вам надо на стороне сервера организовать проверку, что если к вам пришли данные по пользователю, которого нет в списке "неверифицированных", то отдавать ошибку и с данным ничего не делать

А в чём проблема, что кто-то заменит id? Админу это зачем? А другой - доступ иметь не должен.... так что с этим не надо париться............ кстати, отправлять админ должен не свой id, а как минимум его надо по токену определять, токен передавать в запросе.

@АлексейШиманский немного не понял про токен, можете поподробнее?

При авторизации пользователя ему выдаётся уникальный токен, который должен он отсылать каждый запрос например. Это примерно как sessionId .. можно на первых порах и его гонять. а про токены - это в поисковике надо смотреть. можно посмотреть bearer токен и авторизация например

На стороне клиента легко можно посмотреть код .js файла и узнать какие данные, в каком формате и куда отправлять запрос, это небезопасно
Самое популярное решение на данный момент это использование токенов jwt, к примеру можете прочитать эту статью
Есть множество библиотек для удобства работы
Если кратко: метод логина генерирует токен и возвращает его, дальше все запросы подписываются этим токеном, токен не нужно хранить в базе данных, но токен должен "сгорать" по времени, и создаваться новый, к примеру каждые 15 минут.
Таким образом можно обеспечить безопасность приложения
